# image animation issue when clicking a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

I have this code:

```
function CreateAndAnimateEnemyImg() {
  var nh = Math.floor(Math.random() * w + 30);
  var enemy = document.createElement('img');
  enemy.src = 'enemy.jpg';
  enemy.className = 'Enemy';
  pane.append(enemy);
  enemy.onload = function () {
    enemy.style.top = nh + 'px';
  }
}

$("#Start").click(function () {
  var x = setInterval(function () {
    CreateAndAnimateEnemyImg();
    $('.Enemy').animate({ 'left': '-=20px' });
    time--;
  }, 20);

  if (time == 0) {
    timeElapsed = true;
    clearInterval(x);
  }
});
```

And this is the **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SMGtS/1/)**

I know my logic is wrong and I want u to help me to fix my problem on click an new image should be created and animated and a a counter should be initialize when the counter is set to 0 the creation of the new images should be stopped but the created images should still animate to left -20px

Answer (score 0):

Modified the Start click handler little bit. Enemy animate is moved to its own timer and inside the create new enemies interval added check to see if created time reached max.

Here is the new code, updated [fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/SMGtS/5/)

```
$("#Start").click(function () {
  intervalPoint = setInterval(function () {
    CreateAndAnimateEnemyImg();
    time--;
    if (time == 0) 
    StopTimer();
  }, 20);

  setInterval(function () {
    $('.Enemy').animate({ 'left': '-=20px' });
  }, 20);

});

function StopTimer(){
  timeElapsed = true;
  clearInterval(intervalPoint);
  time = 3;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i have changed the position of the clear interval and adde some condition check

```
if (time > 0) {
 $('.Enemy').animate({ 'left': '-=20px' });
 time--;
 console.log(time);
 if(time == 0){
   timeElapsed = true;
   clearInterval(x);
 }
}
```

check here [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/SMGtS/4/)